# Eager load multiple and nested associations

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have three models, `A`, `B` and `C`, where:

```
A.hasMany(B);
B.belongsTo(A);
```

```
B.hasMany(C);
C.belongsTo(B);
```

I'm querying like this:

```
await A.findOne({
    where: { id: id },
    include: [
      {
        model: B,
      },
    ],
  });
```

How can I return the `C` objects that belongs to `B` when querying `A`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end found the solution in the comments of another question.
I need to pass the include with a array like this `[{ all: true, nested: true }]`, I end up having something like this:

```
await A.findOne({
    where: { id: id },
    include: [{ all: true, nested: true }],
});
```

I didn't tested what happens when it loops and also didn't found the docs about it, if a good soul find it feel free to comment it.

Edit:

Nested includes also works:

```
await A.findOne({
    where: { id: id },
    include: [
      {
        model: B,
        include: [
          {
            model: C,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
});
```